# code.gs file variables not returning to Index.html

Tags: javascript, html, variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple WebApp to fetch some data from my spreadsheet.

I have declared wanted data as variables in **code.gs file**

and used them in **index.html file**

But it's **not returning** the variable values,
it's just giving first element of

only ..

what went wrong (or) how to do this ..?

Can anyone help me in this case ..?

Thanks in Advance.

Spreadsheet URL : [enter link description here](https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/10IrV4GQntxZxCbB1gULsa4AX8l8v-LEDYwglPQe9aXUPcB_fNPlvf4s2/edit)

WebApp URL : [enter link description here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzMQtiBvOuZR5r1n-VtgDbZypwWafiYE_O3-VTIP3ourZHeEnq-gH3cd7YmeVhqj4BN/exec)

**code.gs file**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html') 
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

var spreadsheetId   = '16qvXEamrZGNEbCyWMiL2u_OJrHe_XIHLn2eqgQhJYvE';

function gettdslbs() {
  var data1 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, 'SYLLABUSC!A1').values;
  var data2 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, 'SYLLABUSC!A2').values;
  var tdslbs = data1 + "</br> <b>" + data2 + "</b>" ;

  return tdslbs ;
}

function gettrslbs() {
  var data3 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, 'SYLLABUSC!A4').values;
  var data4 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, 'SYLLABUSC!A5').values;
  var trslbs =   data3 + "</br> <b>" + data4 + "</b>" ;
  
  return trslbs ;
}
```

**Index.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

    <script>

        document.getElementById('outputa').innerHTML =  tdslbs ;

        document.getElementById('outputb').innerHTML =  trslbs ;

    </script>

  </head>

  <body style="text-align:center">
    <p> Syllabus in Telugu Language will be fetched from Spreadsheet</p>

    <p id="outputa" ></br> <p style="color:#dd0000" id="outputb"></p></p>

    <p id="test"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a basic example how to do it, you have to complete with your data

Code.gs :

```
function doGet() {

  //use template function instead of output
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index.html');

  //add variable
  template.data = "test";

  return template.evaluate();
}
```

Index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>

    <!-- display "test" here-->
    <p> <?= data ?> </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @Waxim , your code worked very well to pass variables from **Code.gs** to **Index.html**. But now I have created another separate file for script, i.e. **JavaScript.html**. Now variables are not passing from **Code.gs to Javascript.html**